# Is my understanding of finite field division correct?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I've followed this tutorial (http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~jplank/plank/papers/CS-96-332.pdf) which introduces Reed-Solomon coding and therefore covers finite fields. My problem is with one of the examples of how the logarithm and anti logarithm tables are looked up to perform a division. I have included an image of the examples and table below:

[image: Excerpt of log tables and examples]

The tutorial is written for programmers and so $gflog[i]$ is really $log_2(i)$ and $gfilog[i]$ is $log_2^{-1}(i)$.

I am able to follow all but the last example. I used an online finite field calculator which indicates the result should be $10$. The result in the example is $14$, at first I assume this to be a simple mistake of looking up the result in the incorrect row (i.e, looking up the $log_2(i)$ row instead of the $log_2^{-1}(i)$ row) as the
table correctly shows the result should be $10$.

But upon closer inspection, their arithmetic for the indexing into the table seems to be off for the final example, $gfilog[4-10] = gfilog[9]$. Shouldn't the result be $gfilog[10]$?

Now my what I *suspect* is happening is the arithmetic on the indexes is regular integer arithmetic. And in this case, $4-10$ results in $-6$. Since this is an invalid index, and the log tables are over $GF(2^4)$, the correct position of $-6$ is determined by $-6 mod 16$ which gives $10$. However! the $10$ is just the *rank* of the correct index and *not* the index itself. Therefore, the 10th position on the table is really at the 9th index. Hence $gfilog[9] = 10$.

Is my understanding of this correct? I've tried this out with a few other values and it seems to work out. This is all very new to me, so kindly elaborate a bit in your responses as my background is primarily in programming :)

Comment: As others pointed out, the arithmetic of discrete logarithms is carried as that of integers modulo 15 (zero element has no logarithm). Years ago I prepared [a discrete logarithm table](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) of this very field for referrals like this. My notation is a bit different from your sources. My $\gamma$ is your $2$, $\gamma^2=4$, and $\gamma^3=8$, so e.g. my $\gamma^3+\gamma+1$ is your $11$. Anyway, from my table you also see that $$3/7=(\gamma+1)/(\gamma^2+\gamma+1)=\gamma^4/\gamma^{10}=\gamma^{-6}=\gamma^9=\gamma^3+\gamma=8+2=10.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the direct and inverse functions are only defined on $15$ value out of $16$ ($0$ has no logarithm and $15$ no antilogarithm). For this reason, addition and subtraction of the logarithms are performed modulo $15$, not $16$ !

You can spot that in the tutorial, page $7$: $\bmod 2^w-1$ (`NW-1` in the code).

Comment: I fell in the trap as well, years ago.

Comment: This makes me feel a tiny bit better :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The multiplicative group of $GF(2^4)$ is cyclic of order $2^4-1=15$, and $-6\equiv 9\pmod{15}$.

What's happening is that $\log_2$ is a group isomorphism from $GF(2^4)^\times$ to $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$. So when you say "the log tables are over $GF(2^4)$", that's only half correct.